# Is there a way to customize logos is quarto presentations?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I would like to know if this can be done in Quarto presentation: Imagine you have two logos: logo1.png and logo2.png. The objective is using logo1.png in one slide and logo2.png in other slide, in addition I want to have a third slide with no logo at all.
This is requested due to the slide backgrounds used to separate sections of the presentation. In that sense, is it possible to achieve this?
Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

Quarto uses Pandoc for the conversion from Markdown to reveal.js. If you check Pandoc documentation you will find [Background in reveal.js - On individual slides](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#on-individual-slides-reveal.js-pptx):

> To set an image for a particular reveal.js or pptx slide, add
> `{background-image="/path/to/image"}` to the first slide-level heading
> on the slide (which may even be empty).

For example,

```
# Foo {background-image="/path/to/image"}

Bar
```

will be translated into

```
<section id="foo" class="slide level1"
data-background-image="/path/to/image">
<h1 data-background-image="/path/to/image">Foo</h1>
<p>Bar</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I want to achieve is to have interchanged slides and logos. ie. one background with one logo for one topic inside the presentation and other combination for other topic and so on.